# Как повторить действие после ввода в консоль с помощью Scanner?

Tags: java, scanner

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    value = scan.nextInt();
    // some action
}
```

Как можно сделать, чтобы после ввода value и выполнения кода пользователь мог повторить ввод value?

У меня получается это сделать только один раз, после чего нужно программу перезапускать.

Comment: Какое именно условие? Можно использовать циклы, но для чего именно? Какое действие, при каком условии ты хочешь выполнять?

Comment: 0. Я ввожу число. 1. Выполнилась программа (независимо от результата). 3. Могу еще раз ввести число. Неважно как, главное, чтобы можно было повторно вводить.

Comment: бесконечный цикл подойдет?

Comment: вполне. Благодарю

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int value;
    while (true) {
        value = scan.nextInt();
        // some action
    }
}
```